# All of my json is not rendering and container is does not expand

Tags: primeng

I am using the same example code that is on the `primeng` site.

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 bordered tableScroll boxSize">

    <table class="centerTree">
        <p-tree [value]="files" layout="horizontal" [selectionMode]="single"></p-tree>
    </table>

</div>
```

In my service I have the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class NodeService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getFiles() {
        return this.http.get('data.json')
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => <TreeNode[]> res.json().data)
            .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}
```

I also copy and pasted the same JSON from the site. When I inspected the site I seen in the CSS it had a variable named `p-treeNode` so I thought maybe that was the issue so I tried to override it:

```
p-treeNode {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400%;
    color: red;
}
```

Nothing changed I am using the following as a example [PrimeNg Site](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree)

----------------------------Update 1-------------------------

I was able to get all of my JSON render by doing the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.nodeService.getFiles().then(files => {
            this.files = [{
                label: 'Root',
                children: files
            }];
        });
    }
```

I was missing this `label: 'Root',
                    children: files`

however it is still very small and does not look like the sites.

Comment: want to delete the comment with the link to our discussion in your bounty question, I mean since you left your email, and the discussion is public to everyone. So if the link is there, people can see it. Just a thought ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

:host /deep/ .ui-tree { width: 100%; }

to your component css file.